# Which worker need to be use when migrating firebase-job-dispatcher to workmanager?

Tags: android, android-workmanager, firebase-job-dispatcher

To use WorkManager you have to subclass one of the available Worker classes:

- [`ListenableWorker`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ListenableWorker)
- [`Worker`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/Worker)
- [`RxWorker`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/RxWorker)
- [`CoroutineWorker`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/work/CoroutineWorker)

I want to run the job every 2 hours. Some of the answers mentioned should be use Listenable Worker. I am confusing this which one suits to this scenario. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

WorkManager has some [extensive documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) on how to use it that also includes a [migration guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/migrating-fb) covering the move from Firebase JobDispatcher.

In the documentation you can find a section that explain [the different threading behaviour](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/threading) of the different Worker classes.

In your particular case, it really depends if what you want to execute periodically is synchronous or not.

- If what you want to run is synchronous: use a `Worker`
- If what you want to run asynchround: use a `CoroutineWorker` if you're using Kotlin, otherwise you've to use a `ListenableWorker`.